# nginx auth_request: How to add GET parameters after successful authentication

Tags: nginx, flask, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, django-authentication

Sorry this is probably a rather simple question, but I can find nginx rather confusing.

I am using the `auth_request` module in nginx to authenticate users with Django to use a Flask app. If the authentication is successful, I want to retrieve a list of the Django groups the user is part of and add them as GET parameters to the resulting `proxy_pass`. Is there a way to do this?

Here's the relevant portion of what I have so far. To confirm, port 8000 is for the Django authentication and port 8080 is for the Flask app:

```
location /portal/heatmap/ {
    auth_request /auth;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}

location /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/portal/auth;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two issues with this.

1. Conceptually, an authentication module should only be authenticating and shouldn't return anything other than things related to authentication. It should not be adding things unrelated such as a user's groups. So the group information needs to be generated and passed to the authentication module instead of originating from it.
2. But GET parameters are not passed to `auth_module` in nginx. Instead, a header must be added to the `auth_request` which contains the original URI request that includes the GET parameters. To do this, add `proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;` in the authentication location. Then, in the authentication app, the HTML header `X-Original-URI` will have the GET parameters which the app will need to parse.

```
location /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/portal/auth;
    proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```